# Spring boot: how to add spring-data repositories in tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In tests i can add any bean (using static nested configuration class). but how can i add spring-data repositories? i can't return then as new bean because i can't instantiate them - they are interfaces

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
//@SpringBootTest   // or this annotation
public class JTest {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        static class TestEntity {
            String id;
        }

        interface TestRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<TestEntity, String> {}

    }

    @Autowired Config.TestRepository testRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {}
}
```

running with `@DataMongoTest` gives me

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages

running with `@SpringBootTest` gives:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'xxx.JTest$Config$TestRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

how can i add new repositories in tests?

Comment: Are you testing only one class (unit test), or are you testing several classes in combination (functional test)?

Comment: my plan is to test several repositories

Answer (score 2):

Spring doesn't pick up nested interface repository (and instantiate a bean) by default. To enable, see:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@EnableMongoRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class JobTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {

        static class TestEntity {
            String id;
        }
    ....
```

Internally, Spring registers a bean with `new SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID>(..)` if none other specified.

*Edit*
Just realized you are using reactive Mongo. So switch to `EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(..)` instead.